# Exercise 2 , chapter 5 , Stein & Shakarchi real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, integral-transforms

Consider the Mellin transform defined initially for continuous function $f$ of compact support in $R^+=${$t\in R:t>0$} and $x\in R$ by

$Mf(x)=\int_0^\infty f(t)t^{ix-1}dt$

Prove that ($2\pi$)$^{-1/2}M$ extends to a unitary operator from $L^2(R^+,dt/t)$ to $L^2(R)$

I guess it follows the similar way of Theorem 1.1 in chapter 5 (Extension of Fourier transform)

So my plane is 1) $S=\{f\mid  f\mbox{ is continuous of compact support in }R^+\}$ is dense in $R^+$

2) By Lemma 1.3 , $M:S\to L^2$ can be extended to $M':L^2(R^+,dt/t)\to L^2$ (dense $\to$ extend possible under some condition , in fact 3) )

3) For any $f \in S$ , $||f||_{L^2(R^+,dt/t)}=\lVert Mf\rVert_{L^2(R)}$

But it's hard to me.... how can I draw the next step?

Further question : 1. What's the mean of $dt/t$? Does it mean that if $f\in L^2(R^+,dt/t)$ then $\int_0^{\infty} \frac {|f(t)|^2}t <\infty$?

2. Why does the term ($2\pi$)$^{-1/2}$ appear in the extension form?

Answer (score 2):

For the further questions:
1. You are right about the meaning of $dt/t$.

2. The factor $(2\pi)^{-1/2}$ appears in order to make $(2\pi)^{-1/2}M$ unitary.

In order to show that for each $f\in S$, 
$$\lVert f\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb R^+,dt/t)}=(2\pi)^{-1/2} \lVert Mf\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb R)},$$
we can do the substitution $t=e^u$ in the integral defining the Mellin transform. A Fourier transform will appear and we can use Plancherel's formula.